# How to use jquery on click function in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

Recently I used `jqwidgets` i.e grid in my angular project. Here I just put an edit put in each cell which clicked should redirects to edit screen.

I tried in the following ways:

Case 1:

```
var Action = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
    return '<button onClick="open()">EDIT</button>'
}
```

Case 2:

```
var Action = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
    return '<button (Click)="open()">EDIT</button>'
}
```

Case 3:

```
var Action = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
    return '<button routerLink="user/edit/value">EDIT</button>'
}
```

All the above cases failed. Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

My component,

```
var Action = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
    return '<button>EDIT</button>'
}

this.columns = [
    {
        text: 'S.No', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'id', width: 50, cellsalign: 'center'
    },
    {
        text: 'FirstName', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'first_name', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'LastName', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'last_name', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'ServiceType', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'servicetype', width: 50
    },
    {
        text: 'Gender', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'gender', width: 50
    },
    {
        text: 'DateofBirth', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'birthday', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'Location', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'formatted_address', width: 215
    },
    {
        text: 'AdultContentPrivay', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'display_adult_content', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'LoginType', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'logintype', width: 100
    },

    {
        text: 'Groups', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'groups_count', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'Events', columntype: 'textbox', datafield: 'events_count', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'Albums', columntype: 'textbox', datafield: 'albums_count', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'Photos', columntype: 'textbox', width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'Actions', columntype: 'dropdownlist', cellsrenderer: Action, width: 100, filterable: false
    },

    {
        text: 'More', columntype: 'dropdownlist', cellsrenderer: More, width: 100, filterable: false
    }
];
```

Comment: when you are having a lot of plugins in native angular2 why do you go for jQuery. Come out of that jQuery world. Use [**this**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) instead

Comment: Hi Aravind,this looks pretty much better and want to create this in angular 2.

Comment: i didnt get you. elaborate your question

Comment: Amy how I am trying to do this ..so need help atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a [routerLink]="['./SomewhereElse']">Edit</a>
```

Comment: HI Ramya,as this are in jquery   [routerLink] is not working.

Comment: Why wont routerlink work? It is written inside an angular component right?